# how to select specific value depending on a combination of subquery result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Assuming the MyTable below:

```
----------------------------------------
    employee_id task_id Subtask_id  name    pager   checked 
----------------------------------------
    1           124     1           Jackson 555     2015-05-10  
    1           124     2           Jackson 555     2015-06-10  
    1           124     3           Jackson 555     NULL    
    2           789     1           Nancy   333     2015-05-10  
    3           222     1           Jane    555     NULL    
    3           963     1           Jane    555     NULL    
    1           422     1           Jackson 555     2015-06-10  
----------------------------------------
```

I wrote this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT employee_id, task_id, Name, Pager, if(count(Q.employee_ID) > 1,"Incomplete",if(Q.BoolChecked = 0,"None", "Done") AS STATUS
FROM (
SELECT employee_ID, task_id, Name, Pager, if(Checked IS NULL,0,1) AS BoolChecked
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY task_id, BoolChecked
) AS Q
GROUP BY Q.task_id
```

The result is this:

```
----------------------------------------
    employee_id task_id name    pager   checked 
----------------------------------------
    1           124     Jackson 555     Incomplete  
    1           422     Jackson 555     Done    
    2           789     Nancy   333     Done    
    3           222     Jane    555     None
    3           963     Jane    555     None
```

My ultimate goal, which I can't achieve and need help with, is to group by employee_id and get the below result:

```
--------------------------------
    employee_id name    pager   checked 
--------------------------------
    1           Jackson 555     Incomplete  
    2           Nancy   333     Done    
    3           Jane    555     None
```

Summary: per employee_id if all tasks are done, show "Done".  If all tasks are not done, show "None".  Any combo show incomplete"

- Question 1: How can I achieve the final result?
- Question 2: Any performance remarks on the query I already have?

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: How do you decide if its done or complete or incomplete , what is the logic ?

Comment: if all 'subtasks' of a 'task_id' have 'NULL' in 'checked' column = task 'not done'.
if all 'subtasks' of a 'task_id' have a date in 'checked' column = task 'done'.
Else, 'incomplete'

Comment: How does your subquery GROUP BY employee & boolchecked when it's also including name and task_id (task_id changes within employee_id=3)

Comment: But for the desired final result, if an employee has some tasks done and some none, she gets incomplete.  All done = complete and all NULL = none.  I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Wait - is it per TASK or per EMPLOYEE?! Your latest edit changed things!

Comment: I fixed an error based on your first comment.  To clarify, I was able to group by task_id but my goal is to group by employee_id.  The final 'checked' column should reflect the status of all tasks per employee.  Thanks Peter I appreciate you taking the time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count(*)` counts all rows, whereas `count(expression)` counts rows where `expression IS NOT NULL`. As what you need is actually numer of rows where `expression IS NULL` - the simplest way is to just subtract theese two values. Try this:

```
SELECT
  `employee_id`, `name`, `pager`
  , CASE 
    WHEN (count(*) - count(`checked`)) > 0 THEN 'Incomplete'
    ELSE 'done'
   END AS checked
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY `employee_id`, `name`, `pager`
```

**here's the fiidle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df620/3**

Second thing: assuming that 'nancy' has only unfinished tasks - why would you want her to be marked as "none" ? To be able to tell so, you would need to redesign your schema. Split your table into two: "employees" and "tasks". Then you can do a left join - if there are no rows for some employee - then you can mark him as 'NONE'. If you really want it your way - you can try below query:

```
SELECT
  `employee_id`, `name`, `pager`
  , CASE 
    WHEN max(`checked`) IS NULL AND min(`checked`) IS NULL THEN 'none'
    WHEN (count(*) - count(`checked`)) > 0 THEN 'Incomplete'
    ELSE 'done'
   END AS checked
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY `employee_id`, `name`, `pager`
```

**And a fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df620/5**

Comment: Second query works for my purpose.  To answer your question "why would you want her to be marked as "none"?" it's because an employee could be assigned a task but hasnt checked-in yet.  So if an employee does not exist in this table, it means no task assigned.  Thanks so much Murison!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the whole thing without a sub-query, just grouping and using conditionals. Note that `CASE` would be better than `IF` but I'm too lazy to look up the syntax on that:

```
SELECT employee_id, name, pager, 
    SUM(IF(checked IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS NullCount,
    SUM(IF(checked IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS CompleteCount,
    IF(NullCount > 0 AND CompleteCount > 0, 
        'Incomplete', 
        IF(CompleteCount > 0, 'Done', 'None') AS Status
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY employee_id, name, `pager`
```

Again, it would be and look better if you replaced the nested `IF()` with `CASE`. If it bothers you to have the NullCount and CompleteCount as extra columns then you could just put them within the `IF` - it just seemed to make it a lot clearer this way (and didn't require a double-count for the CompleteCount).

I looked up the CASE - here it is, fully untested:

```
SELECT employee_id, name, pager, 
    SUM(IF(checked IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS NullCount,
    SUM(IF(checked IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS CompleteCount,
    CASE
        WHEN (SUM(IF(checked IS NULL, 1, 0)) > 0 AND SUM(IF(checked IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) > 0) THEN 'Incomplete'
        WHEN (SUM(IF(checked IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) > 0) THEN 'Done'
        ELSE 'None' 
    END AS Status
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY employee_id, name, `pager`
```

Comment: Peter, I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Apparently you can't use the aliases as I did - when I replace it with the SUM() (and also quote the apparently-reserved-word "pager") it works.